# What is the opposite of "did-fail-load" event

Tags: javascript, electron

I know [did-fail-load](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-did-fail-load) event can detect invalid URL cases in the electron browser window. But I need the opposite situation. I need to something like `did-success-load`

I tried [did-finish-load](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-did-finish-load). This event also firing in fail cases too

Comment: Is the `ready-to-show` event on BrowserWindow fired on fail too?

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no event that is only fired on successful page loads. If you use `BrowserWindow.loadURL` (or `contents.loadURL`), you can use the fact that these [return a promise](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winloadurlurl-options):

```js
mainWindow.loadURL(myURL).then(() => {
    console.log('Successful page load')
}).catch(() => {
    console.log('Page load failed')
})
```

Here, either the promise resolves and the success message is printed, or the promise rejects and the error is shown.